# Trying to implement a variadic min() function in C++

Tags: c++

I have some code that seems to me like it ought to work but throws an error when compiling.

The header file (`min.hpp`):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace test {

    template <typename T1>
    T1 min(T1 a);
    template <typename T1, typename ... Args>
    typename std::common_type<T1, Args...>::type min(T1 a, Args ... args);

}
```

The implementation (`min.cpp`):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace test {

    template <typename T1>
    T1 min(T1 a)
    {
        return a;
    }
    template <typename T1, typename ... Args>
    typename std::common_type<T1, Args...>::type min(T1 a, Args ... args)
    {
        typename std::common_type<Args...>::type b = min(args...);
        return a > b ? b : a;
    }

}
```

Calling the function (`demo.cpp`):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "min.hpp"

int main()
{
    int x = test::min(1, 2, 3);
    std::printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:
`g++ min.cpp demo.cpp -std=gnu++17 -o main`

Error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::common_type<int, int, int>::type test::min<int, int, int>(int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in demo-5e729b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

However, the code works fine if I move the `main()` function from the separate file to `min.cpp`.
Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: your template definitions need to be in the header

Comment: Not the answer, but A: we already have `std::min({1,2,3})`, and B: consider using a fold expression instead of recursion.

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles. I didn't realize that.

Comment: Related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: @mwpuppire Also, the error is not a compiler error.  It is a linker error (`ld` is the linker).  You will see that the object file `demo-5e729b.o` was successfully created, meaning the compilation went through without any issues.  It is the linker that is complaining that the function you're calling can't be found.